# How to skip cached properties in inspect.getmembers

Tags: python

I have a python class Foo that registers observers to an observable.
I have several classes that inherits from Foo and populate the list of observers, each with different observers.

**For reasons related to the current design, the list of observers is initialized explicitly in every derived class __init__ and cannot be moved to an overridable method (that would be called from the base class __init__).**

As a result I can't call observable.RegisterObservers in the constructor (because the list of observers is not populated yet).

To make sure that the observers are registered, I created the observable as cached property. This way I can guarantee that no one will access the field directly without registering the observers first.

The first call to my_observable should have happened after init is done.
The problem is that there is an inspect.getmembers call at the end of the base class init.
inspect.getmembers() uses getattr, and by that evaluates the cached_property.

I tried to throw AttributeError if some condition is not met (i.e. we are still in the init), but I don't like this solution, and it would fail if someone will implement the derived class in a different way.
Is there a way to tell inspect to skip cached properties? 
Also ok to have a trusted way to tell if init (of derived classes) is done.

Pseudo code:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._observers = []
    for _, member in inspect.getmembers(self):
      # do something with member
      continue

  @cached_property
  def my_observable:
    observable = Observable()
    observable.RegisterObservers(self._observers)
    return observable


class Bar(Foo):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Bar, self).__init__()
    self._observers = [MyObserver()]
```

Comment: How about use a flag in `__init__`? For example, set `initialized` to be `True` at the end.

Comment: I thought about that, but derived class will call __init__ of super and only then execute their own init.. so this flag should be set in the derived class init...

Comment: I think rather to prevent wrong implementation by hard-coding, a well-formatted documentation is more helpful... As your users are also programmers, they should implement derived class rightly.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for my problem.
It doesn't solve the inspect.getmembers evaluating my cached property, but it actually solves the design issue in a much better way.

I will define a meta class that will override the **call** and will call a specific method on the class.
overriding **call** in a metaclass lets us inject that step just before the new instance is returned.

So it will look something like this:

```
class MyMetaClass(type): 
  def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
      """Called when the object is initialized."""
      obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
      obj.FinalizeInit()
      return obj


class Foo(object):
  __metaclass__ = MyMetaClass
  def __init__(self):
    self._observers = []
    for _, member in inspect.getmembers(self):
      # do something with member
      continue
    self._observable = None

  def FinalizeInit(self):
    self._observable = Observable()
    self._observable.RegisterObservers(self._observers)
```